# Unable to Scroll to the Top of the Table of Contents in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I’m trying to set up a Table of Contents for Jupyter Notebook. However, there is no scroll bar for the table of contents and I’m unable to scroll all the way up to see what the headings look like. Anyone know of a solution to this problem? Thanks in advance!

I’ve looked at the settings for the Table of Contents on the notebook extensions and still haven’t been able to figure it out.